# VitePress: Insert markdown text into Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, markdown, vitepress

I want to use markdown formatting in my Vue components in VitePress. Something like

`./comp/Page.vue`: main Vue component that includes other Vue components

```html
<script setup>
    import Part1 from './parts/Part1.vue';
    ...
</script>

<template>
    <Part1/>
    ...
</template>
```

`./comp/parts/Part1.vue`: Vue component with markdown formatting inside

```html
<script setup>
    import Markdown from '...';
</script>

<template>
    <Markdown>
        ### Heading

        * List Item
        * List Item
        * List Item
    </Markdown>
</template>
```

Is it possible in VitePress?